# How to set WantAuthnRequestsSigned to false in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak

i'm using keycloak and I want to change this attribute WantAuthnRequestsSigned to false in SAML Identity Provider Metadata,
thx

Answer (score 1):

Just edit the saved SAML IDP metadata xml file and change `WantAuthnRequestsSigned` to `false` directly.
You also need to TURN OFF `Client Signature Required` in your client settings.

Based on [the source code](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/860fc4c06c1690db6fdf78da47ee7cd8a2a3a04e/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/protocol/saml/SamlService.java#L864), `WantAuthnRequestsSigned` is hardcoded as true. But it doesn't matter.